# How to display tinyint values as Month name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have credit card ExpiryDate stored as tinyint. I would like to see them as Jan, Feb, etc instead of 1,2,... the following works, but what other way is this possible?

```
SELECT ExpMonth, CHOOSE(ExpMonth, 'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec')
FROM Sales.CreditCard
```

Comment: CASE statements also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on 2012 or above...

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(2000,ExpMonth,1),'MMM','en-US')
```

Or just create a lookup table with the mappings and join onto that.

Answer (score 1):

Format() would be my first choice for a limited number of records.

Just a couple more options.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table(ExpMonth int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1),(3),(12)

SELECT ExpMonth
     , Option2 = left(datename(month,datefromparts(1900,ExpMonth,1)),3)
     , Option3 = substring('  JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec',ExpMonth*3,3)
FROM @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
ExpMonth    Option2 Option3
1           Jan     Jan
3           Mar     Mar
12          Dec     Dec
```

Comment: option 3 is very creative!

Comment: @Eli Had to reach deep into my quiver for that arrow,  That one goes all the way back to my dBase II days.  (Just in case ... early 80's)

Answer (score 0):

This should help you convert:

```
WHILE (select <yourValue> from <yourtable>) < 13
BEGIN
    declare @monthNum int;
    set @monthNum = <yourValue>

    select datename(month, dateadd(month, @monthNum - 1, 0)) as MonthName
END
```